# How to change permission to access my flash drive?

Tags: usb-drive, thunar

[image]

Why are so many files marked with a lock here?. And I can't do anything on my flash drive, like copying, pasting, except for read file only.

Note : Many files that I have is using Indonesian language.

[image: This is my USB drive configuration]

This is my USB drive configuration, in sdb1 as FAT32

Comment: Is this flash drive used with Windows as well as in Ubuntu? Did you unplug it "safely"? Add these information in your answer. Also add a a screenshot of the app **Disks** in your question highlighting the flash drive on the left panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are so many files marked with a lock here? And I can't do anything on my flashdrive, like copying, pasting, except for read file only.

Because it is mounted as read-only or mounted with write enabled but not owned  by you.

- if the drive is ext4 you can do this from a terminal session if it is not owned by you:

  ```
  cd /media/muhammadhikamz/
  sudo chown -r $USER:$USER E16C-15FE
  ```
- if the drive is formatted as NTFS you need to mount it with read/write and a couple of options. An example could be ...

  ```
  sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/{device} /media/muhammadhikamz/E16C-15FE
  ```

  - `-t vfat` instead of `-t ntfs` if FAT
  - 0222 is read/write for owner, group, and others and is a reversed chmod permissions. Adjust as needed but do not use execute permissions (those are reserved for POSIX compliant filesystems; NTFS is not).
  - the utf-8 is likely not needed so you might want to omit it or if needed alter it for Indonesian support.

... and the locks will disappear.

Comment: My USB Drive is not using NTFS, but using FAT32

Comment: I very thankful for your advice